# cURL with PUT method

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to do a cURL request with the PUT method using only a URL? Here is the URL i would like to be able to call using cURL with the PUT method:

`$url = https://url.net/card/activate.xml?card_id=1234567890&application_key=123123&accesskey=abcdef`

I was able to make it work using the REST Console(Chrome Extension) but not using cURL. I tried using `curl_setopt` with `CURLOPT_PUT`, `CURLOPT_INFILE` and `CURLOPT_INFILESIZE` but I was receiving an empty page, no response at all.

This is the headers and curl options I currently have:

```
$header[] = 'Authorization: Basic abc123';
$header[] = 'Accept: text/xml';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($soap_do);
```

Currently, with those settings, I'm getting the 411 Length Required error. Would it be possible to make it work like that or am I trying to configure something that will never work?

Comment: Maybe `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-length: 0'));`? (or rather, add to your existing header)

Comment: I added Content-Length: 0 to my headers array and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The HTTP 411 Error

> The Web server (running the Web site) thinks that the HTTP data stream sent by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) should include a 'Content-Length' specification. This is typically used only for HTTP methods that result in the placement of data on the Web server, not the retrieval of data from it.

You need to set the Content Length of your Data

```
$header[] = 'Content-length: '.strlen($put_data);
```

OR If you don't have any data, just put `0` there.

Comment: It worked by setting the Content-Length: 0 in the headers. I thought the Content-Length was used by the request and needed to be the length of the data sent or else it wouldn't work.